# Call method(ProjectActivity) from another Library Activity

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity

I want to call one method from library but the method is written in Activity of project   how can i achieve this:

Activity.java from (myProject):

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public void favorite(String Str[], Context cxt) {
    }
}
```

Library Activity(Modules(LibraryFile))

```
public class MuPDFActivity extends Activity{
   //Here I want to call( favorite(String Str[], Context cxt)) this method.
}
```

Please anyone help me with this issue.

Comment: What problem u are getting in calling a method from another class?

Comment: i am not calling method from another class, i am calling from library Activity@ρяσѕρєяK

Comment: You can't call Main project method/class from library class. If you want this behavior then you should create a separate library which contains code common in Main project and library project. Another way is to register a broadcast in activity and send it from library. In activity once you get the broadcast you can call your method.

Comment: any other way to achive this concept@SagarTrehan